# The maui always returns .apk with a date modified 1/1/1981

Tags: .net-core, maui

We build

```
dotnet publish Mobile.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-android -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR
```

a maui .apk via to docker gitlab runner on base mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.101.
In the Release mode we always get a date modified 1/1/1981. If build without the docker or in a debug mode the date modified is correct. Does anybody know a reason?[image]